# Stream Example not working

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to run the stream example given on https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk. It successfully loads on the emulator. It shows Welcome to stream message along with fconnect button.

[image]

But when i click on fconnect button it goes to the home screen. Nothing happens.

What is the reason for such strange behavior i am unable to understand?

Please help me on this

Thanks,

Pankaj

Comment: Try to debug and see where the pointer is getting lost... i think its the dialog problem, do the emulator have facebook application in it?

Comment: @farhan thanks for replying. Yes there is simple application which i have removed

Answer (score 0):

According to README file

Here's a few common errors and their solutions.

- **Build error: "missing gen files".**

  This should go away when you rebuild the project. If you have trouble, try running **Clean...** from the **Project** menu.
- **Error: "invalid_key"**

  This error means that the Facebook server doesn't recognize your Android key hash. Make sure that you correctly generated and copy/pasted your key hash into the Facebook developer settings console (http://www.facebook.com/developers/apps.php), and make sure that your application has been signed with the same key you registered with Facebook.
- **Dialog won't load or shows a blank screen.**

  This can be tricky to debug. If the logs don't give an indication of what's wrong, I suggest installing tcpdump on your device and getting a trace. Tutorial: http://www.vbsteven.be/blog/android-debugging-inspectin-network-traffic-with-tcpdump/

  If you still can't tell what's going on, then file an issue and please include the HTTP trace.
- **I can't upload photos with photos.upload.**

  Make sure the Bundle value for the photo parameter is a byte array.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the existing emulator which has platform 2.3.3 then created new emulator with platform 2.2 and then ran the example it ran fine.